# What policies does the U.S have for Yemen crisis?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, yemen

At least for the last 6 months the war between Saudis and Yemen has been intensified and thousands of Yemenis were killed during this period.

According to [news](http://www.presstv.ir/Detail/2015/09/21/430114/Yemen-Saudi-Arabia-Sanaa-Hasbah-Sawan) like [this](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2015/09/24/yemen-mosque-bombing/72724148/), recent bombings caused multiple casualties in Yemen and they were mostly Children and non-military people.

We haven't seen any positive movements from U.S so this brings up the question:

What are U.S policies for this crisis, if any, and why isn't U.S helping Yemen as a humanitarian act, if they support peace in M.E?

Comment: I believe the official term for Obama Administration policy in such cases is "[leading from behind](http://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/leading-from-behind)".

Comment: Also, incidentally, we know what the UN policy for Yemen crisis is. Pass a resolution condemning Israel :)

Comment: @user4012 If that will help the situation in Yemen then why not? ;)

Comment: But frankly history showed us the UN policies have never been a problem for Israel regime. take 2014 for example, at least 2000 children were killed by Israel regime, yet they're not condemned for anything.

Comment: including teenage Hamas fighters in "Children" is a wee bit disingenuous, no?

Comment: @user4012 If a regime invade your country and rape your family and burn your children alive, would You sit like a carrot and let them do anything they want? even though you know you have no chance against them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

US policy is supporting Saudi government and  the ongoing killing of innocent people in Yemen, as US  will supply bombs worth USD 1.29 billion to Saudis.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-34838937

So Saudi aggression against Yemen can go on for some time and they can also arm ISIS in Syria and Iraq with the newest US killing technology.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer hasn't caught the eye of anyone yet.

Comment: ISIS in Syria and Iraq = the Islamic State in Syria and Iraq in Syria and Iraq

Answer (score 3):

The US and UK (in contradiction to the EU) provide military support to the Saudi government and its coalition partners in their military action in Yemen. The US provides intelligence information and air tanker refueling for the Saudi Royal Airforce. The UK government sold $4.2 billion dollars with of military equipment and armaments to the Saudi government in 2015.

The US recognizes the current President of Yemen (Hadi) and his government as the legitimate government of Yemen. The Saudi-led Arab Coalition is in support of the Hadi government (Operation Decisive Storm) retaking full control of the country. The military action is against the Houthi militia, which captured the capital last year, and is allegedly supported/funded by Iran.

Many see this as a proxy war for regional influence between Saudi Arabia and Iran.

Here is a summary article (which my media site published) relating to US/UK involvement in Yemen:

http://www.sincere.global/blog/international-middle-east.php#224